# Undelete bad designed deleted C++ functions

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Due to a mistake when designing an interface, a third-party software provider deleted a function, like the copy constructor in class base_noncopy_base:

```
class base_noncopy_base {
    base_noncopy_base(const base_noncopy_base&);
    public:
    base_noncopy_base() {}
};
```

That class is supposed to be inherited, like:

```
class base_noncopy_derived : public base_noncopy_base {
    // whatever ....
};
```

But now, it is no longer allowed to use base_noncopy_derived as a base_noncopy_base:

```
int main() {
    base_noncopy_derived d;
    // base_noncopy_base b1 = d; // won't compile
    // base_noncopy_base b2(d); // won't compile
    // base_noncopy_base b3((base_noncopy_derived)d); // won't compile
}
```

It is possible to `const_cast` a `const` member, and I have seen some hacks out there to access private members from outside a class, of course, only to be used in emergency cases. I am wondering:  would there be any possibility of hacking the deletion of a function out?

Edit 1:

Elaborating further the question:

The actual problem arises from other third-party functions functions, like:

```
void base_noncopy_function1(base_noncopy_base &b) {
}

void base_noncopy_function2(base_noncopy_base b) {
```

}

I can use something like:

```
base_noncopy_base *b4 = &d;
base_noncopy_function1(*b4);
```

But not

```
base_noncopy_function2(*b4);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to be using a pointer to `base_noncopy_base`? Otherwise, why inherit from it at all?

Comment: if you have the sorce code, can't you just change it?

Comment: are you sure that this is design-by-mistake? Maybe there are good reasons not to copy object of this class (or subclasses)

Comment: Do you really want to slice the object, copying just the base part to a new object? Are you sure you don't want a base-class reference or pointer to the existing object?

Comment: @Collin , at MiKe I added the Edit 1, so now it is easier to see why I was using full objects. at David where did I tell I have it? I need to edit the question so. at tobi303 Who knows? But that doesn't change the question "would there be any possibility of hacking the deletion of a function out?"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "use `base_noncopy_derived` as a `base_noncopy_base`", then use a reference or pointer rather than creating a new object:

```
base_noncopy_derived d;
base_noncopy_base & b = d;
```

Your commented-out code attempts to slice the base class, creating a new object by copying just part of `d`. This is rarely a sensible thing to do, and the reason why base classes tend to be abstract or non-copyable.

If you really want to do this, then you'll have to change the definition of the base class so that it doesn't delete the copy functions. There's no way to "undelete" them.